# Java - Read BZ2 file and uncompress/parse on the fly

Tags: java, compression, io

I have a fairly large BZ2 file that with several text files in it. Is it possible for me to use Java to uncompress certain files inside the BZ2 file and uncompress/parse the data on the fly? Let's say that a 300mb BZ2 file contains 1 GB of text. Ideally, I'd like my java program to say read 1 mb of the BZ2 file, uncompress it on the fly, act on it and keep reading the BZ2 file for more data. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that bzip2/bz2 files are compressed single files. They are not archives that can contain more than one file (or directories) like zip or other formats.

Answer (score 33):

The commons-compress library from apache is pretty good. Here's their samples page:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html

Here's the latest maven snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And here's my util method:

```
public static BufferedReader getBufferedReaderForCompressedFile(String fileIn) throws FileNotFoundException, CompressorException {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    CompressorInputStream input = new CompressorStreamFactory().createCompressorInputStream(bis);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    return br2;
}
```

Comment: Note: the accepted formats are: gzip, bzip2, xz, lzma, Pack200, DEFLATE and Z. As seen in the link, the correct one is automatically assigned

Answer (score 3):

The Ant project contains a [bzip2](http://www.kohsuke.org/bzip2/) library. Which has a `org.apache.tools.bzip2.CBZip2InputStream` class. You can use this class to decompress the bzip2 file on the fly - it just extends the standard Java [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) class.

Comment: This library didn't recognize my bzip2 format. Had to use commons-compress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.bzip2.BZip2CompressorInputStream` from Apache commons-compress

```java
InputStream inputStream = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlBz2File), true) // true should be used for big files, as I understand
```

and than `org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils`:

```java
    int pos = 0;
    int step = 1024 * 32;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[step];
    int actualLength = 1;
    while (actualLength > 0) {
        actualLength = IOUtils.readFully(inputStream, buffer, pos, step);
        pos += actualLength;
        String str = new String(buffer, 0, actualLength, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        // something what you want to do
    }
```

But it may be hard to deal with back presure (consumer may be faster then producer and vice versa). So I tried to use Akka Streams with `BZip2CompressorInputStream`.