# BZip2 compressed input for Apache Flink

Tags: bzip2, apache-flink

I have a wikipedia dump compressed with bzip2 (downloaded from http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/), but I don't want to unpack it: I want to process it while decompressing on the fly.

I know that it's possible to do it in plain Java (see e.g. [Java - Read BZ2 file and uncompress/parse on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834721/java-read-bz2-file-and-uncompress-parse-on-the-fly/)), but I was wondering how do it in Apache Flink? What I probably need is something like https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop but for Flink, not Hadoop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to read compressed files in the following formats in Apache Flink:

```java
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
```

As you can see from the package names, Flink does this using Hadoop's InputFormats.
This is an example for reading <kbd>gz</kbd> files using Flink's Scala API:
(You need at least Flink 0.8.1)

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  val job = new JobConf()
  val hadoopInput = new TextInputFormat()
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/robert/Downloads/cawiki-20140407-all-titles.gz"))
  val lines = env.createHadoopInput(hadoopInput, classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], job)

  lines.print

  env.execute("Read gz files")
}
```

Apache Flink has only build-in support for <kbd>.deflate</kbd> files. Adding support for more compression codecs is easy to do, but hasn't been done yet.

Using HadoopInputFormats with Flink doesn't cause any performance loss. Flink has build-in serialization support for Hadoop's `Writable` types.