# Spring Batch: How to configure a FlatItemFileReader to read a compressed ND-JSON file?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-batch

#### Input

New line delimited JSON, sample:

```
{"summersolstice":"21st June, 2019", //complex objects, arrays, etc ... }
{"summersolstice":"21st June, 2018", //complex objects, arrays, etc ... }
{"summersolstice":"21st June, 2017", //complex objects, arrays, etc ... }
```

#### Constraint

While I understand the best way is to be using the shiny new JSON item reader devs released last summer ([link](https://spring.io/blog/2018/05/31/spring-batch-4-1-0-m1-released#add-a-new-json-item-reader)), it isn't feasible to update the batch version to the latest one yet. That is the only constraint.

#### Present Approach

As of now, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928967/spring-batch-how-to-setup-a-flatfileitemreader-to-read-a-json-file) stack answer, but I don't think having a `T` for `FlatFileItemReader` as `Map<String, Object>` is the best strategy!
As of now I just take it in with this code:

```
public class JsonItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, Object>> {

    public JsonItemReader(File file) {
        Resource resource = new BzipLazyResource(file); //on the fly unzipping
        setResource(resource);
        setLineMapper(new JsonLineMapper());
    }

    public JsonItemReader(String sourceFileName) {
        this(new File(sourceFileName));
    }
}
```

...and then parse it simply in an ItemProcessor, like:

```
public class JsonItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Map<String, Object>, List<Json>> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonItemProcessor.class);

    public List<Json> process(Map<String, Object> jsonItem) throws Exception {
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(jsonItem);
        return parseJsonItems(jsonNode);
    }
```

#### Resources:

- [Spring Batch: How to setup a FlatItemFileReader to read from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928967/spring-batch-how-to-setup-a-flatfileitemreader-to-read-a-json-file)
- [How to convert HashMap to JsonNode with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391095/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-jsonnode-with-jackson)
- [New line delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/)
- [How to read compressed files on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834721/java-read-bz2-file-and-uncompress-parse-on-the-fly)
- [Batch 4.1.x JsonItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/json/JsonItemReader.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for such an indirection by extending `FlatFileItemReader` and creating an additional item processor to convert `Map<String, Object>` to a `List<Json>`..

Here is a quick line mapper you can use with the `FlatFileItemReader`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;

public class NDJsonLineMapper<T> implements LineMapper<T> {

    private Class<? extends T> targetType;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // TODO could make this configurable

    public NDJsonLineMapper(Class<? extends T> targetType) {
        this.targetType = targetType;
    }

    @Override
    public T mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        return objectMapper.readValue(line, targetType);
    }
}
```

And its test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class NDJsonLineMapperTest {

    @Test
    void testNDJsonMapping() throws Exception {
        // given
        String jsonLine = "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"foo\"}";
        NDJsonLineMapper<Person> lineMapper = new NDJsonLineMapper<>(Person.class);

        // when
        Person person = lineMapper.mapLine(jsonLine, 1);

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(1, person.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals("foo", person.getName());

    }

    static class Person {

        private int id;
        private String name;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

This is an example of option 1.2 in the link you shared. You can use it with the `FlatFileItemReader` as follows:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("NDJsonItemReader")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("file.ndjson"))
            .lineMapper(new NDJsonLineMapper<>(Person.class))
            .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It was quite helpful. My case is that the JSON happens to be very nested. So I wanted a way to be able to traverse it without having to make a `Person` like representation for it! Thanks!